# Python String format width wrong when characters like é or ö in the string

Tags: python, string, format

Using simple field width specifier, the columns are 'thinner' when the string includes 'European' characters. I have a small script to print out various fields from a Django DB (last_name, first_name, email etc), and the columns are 1 character less for each such character in the string

example:

```
         Johansen
       lövström
```

Printed using `"%20s" % field.encode('utf-8')`

Any ideas whats going on?? (and how to fix)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, ö encodes as two bytes in UTF-8. And your format specifies 20 bytes.

You could try to format while still in the unicode string world, where %20s would mean 20 characters, and convert the formatted result to utf-8.

Comment: Awesome thanks, worked a charm... constructed the row string and them encode to utf-8 to output (instead of each field) - shorter code to! Didn't realise the width was in bytes...