# Format : wrong string width when UTF-8 encoding

Tags: python, excel, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I get an wrong format output, when I have characters like "ä", "ü" "ö", etc. 
I read names from an excel-sheet-column, which have sometimes Unicode strings, which I encode to UTF-8. My simplified code:

```
import xlrd

name1 = (xl_sheet.cell_value(row,5)).encode('utf8') # use this because this cell can have strings with chars like "ö" 
name2 = (xl_sheet.cell_value(row,7)).encode('utf8')

print('{:<15} {:<15}'.format(name1,name2)),
```

When I don't use the .encode, I got this error:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf6' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I found  a similar post: [Python String format width wrong when characters like é or ö in the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990988/python-string-format-width-wrong-when-characters-like-%C3%A9-or-%C3%B6-in-the-string), but I don't know how to implement that in my case!?

My output table is like that:

```
oabcd           oabcd
öabcd          oabcd
oabcd           oabcd
```

When f.e. char 'ö' is in the variable, then the output isn't right.

The Excel-File has CP-1252 "Windows Unicode" encoding.

Output of xlrd.open_workbook(filename).encoding is: utf_16_le.

Answer (score 2):

it was quite simple:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

do the trick. The .encode('utf8') in the main code is not necessary.

Comment: Ooh. Nice. You don't need the `reload(sys)` part though, if you're importing it right away. :)

Answer (score 1):

(I'll assume you're printing Latin script only. If you mix scripts this will get really complicated and you should probably <del>ask a question</del> search for an answer specifically about that)

A possible issue when doing this are combining marks. An accented letter like `ö` can be saved as two Unicode characters, the `o` and the combining `¨`. Those are 2 characters but take up only one space when printed. For many combinations there is also a combined form `ö` which encodes that letter in one character. So:

```
>>> len("ö")
2
>>> len("ö")
1
```

You can try to use `unicodedata.normalize('NFC', name)` to convert those pairs to the combining forms, but it will not work in all cases because not all combinations have a combined form.

And as both zizouz and the question you linked point out, do not encode those strings before printing them. Both `print` and `string.format` work with unicode strings.

Answer (score 0):

The post that you linked actually recommends not encoding anything, and keeping everything in unicode. For your example, it would look more like:

```
name1=u'öabcd'
name2='oabcd'
print(u'{:<15} {:<15}'.format(name1,name2)),
```

Since you're not saving the variable for use later anyways, don't worry about encoding and decoding the strings. You'll just confuse yourself even more :)

Comment: That was just a simple example. I have a variable earlier in the program. When i try your suggestion, i got the error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128). Therefore i used the .encode().

Comment: So then you are saving the variable for user later on... In essence, the post that you had linked to recommends doing everything in unicode, and to not bother with ascii and encoding stuff. That should fix the space issue that you get in your `print` statement. Do you think you can update your question with the offending code?